# openssl and openssh-server on the same system

Tags: package-management, openssh, openssl

I have installed both openssl and openssh on my ubuntu bionic machine. OpenSSH by design seems to use a (slightly) older version of the openssl library whereas OpenSSL (the package) uses a different version

Will this cause any (potential) conflict or breakage on the system??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are these dependencies on 18.04, which you seem to talk about in your question:

- [openssh-server](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/openssh-server) (or [openssh-client](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/openssh-client)) → [libssl1.0.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/libssl1.0.0)
- [openssl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/openssl) → [libssl1.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/libssl1.1)

However, while `libssl1.0.0` and `libssl1.1` are both variants of the same library, they are different packages, because the major/minor version component is included in the package and file names. One is not an update of the other, but instead they can coexist on the same system just fine.

There is no conflict or breaking relation between those two declared in the packages themselves:

```
$ apt show libssl1.1 libssl1.0.0 | grep -E '^(Package|Breaks):'

Package: libssl1.1
Breaks: isync (<= 1.3.0-1build1), python-boto (<= 2.44.0-1ubuntu2), python-httplib2 (<= 0.9.2+dfsg-1), python-imaplib2 (<= 2.57-1), python3-boto (<= 2.44.0-1ubuntu2), python3-imaplib2 (<= 2.57-1)
Package: libssl1.0.0
```

You can also compare the list of files provided by [libssl1.0.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/libssl1.0.0/filelist) and [libssl1.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/amd64/libssl1.1/filelist) and you will find no overlap.

So no, there should be no problems when installing both `openssl` and `openssh-*` packages. Also if there were any, `apt` should tell you that during the installation process before messing up.